# Dealing with memory leaks in socket program

Tags: python, sockets, memory-leaks

I am not much experienced in socket programming and threading in python. I am working on tracking devices that sends GPS positional data to sever. Devices works on Long connection mode, which means once a device connects to server, it keep the connection alive for (many) hours.

When I check Ubuntu system resource usage (with top or htop), I see my processes have increasing Virtual and Resident Memory usage. Process starts with ~55 MB Virtual Memory and ~12 MB Resident Memory. After 3 days, the Virtual memory is increased to ~14 GB while Resident memory usage is about ~90MB.

That statistics do not seem normal to me, virtual and resident memory usage never drop, which suspects me of memory leaks. Since I am not very experienced with threading and socket programming, I have hard time inspecting possible problems.

My code is as below:

```
_log = Logger("Orion_EasyTrac").create_logger()

server = Server("", 9985, logger=_log)
server.start()
```

`Server` class

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, host, sock_port, buffsize=8192, logger=None):
        self.hostname = host
        self.sock_port = sock_port
        self.buffsize = buffsize
        self.socket = None
        self.log = logger or _log

    def start(self):
        self.log.info("Listening: {prt}".format(prt=self.sock_port))
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind((self.hostname, self.sock_port))
        self.socket.listen(5)

        while True:
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()
            thread.start_new_thread(EasyTrackProHandler(conn=conn, buff_size=self.buffsize, log=self.log).handle_data, ())
```

Basic part of `EasyTrackPro`

```
class EasyTrackPro(object):
    def __init__(self, conn, buff_size, log):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff_size = buff_size
        self.log = log
        self.db_conn = None                         
        self.cursor = None                          
        self.db_connector = None                    
        self.ack_parameter = None
        self.device_id = None
        self.user_id = None
        self.beaconID = None
        self.error_count = 0

    ...
    ...

    def handle_data(self):
        while True:
            try:
                _veri = self.conn.recv(self.buff_size)
                if not _veri:
                    # We do not recieve any data...
                    raise NoIncomingDataException()
            except NoIncomingDataException:
                # No need to log anything in here...
                break
            except Exception as h_e:
                self.log.exception(self._log_msg("Socket exception {h_e}".format(h_e=h_e)))
                break
            else:
                self.control_data(_veri)
        self.conn.close()
```

`self.control_data(_veri)` is part that do the job, but since it is quite long and complicated, it do not seem logical to share that part.

`Logger` is a class that uses python `logging` module and logs to text files.

My guess is, Garbage collector fails in collecting old objects or since the devices uses long connections, server side never closes an opened socket. But not sure about any of them.

What may be the problem of this memory leak?

UPDATE: My logger class

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, log_name, level='INFO', log_dir='logs', log_format=None, handler=None):
        """
        log_name:   log file name
        level:      log levels: CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
        log_dir:    log folder. default <file_path>/logs/
        log_format: logging format
        handler:    TODO (incomplete)
        """
        self.__log_name = log_name
        self.__formatter = None
        self.__handler = handler
        self.__level = None
        self.__log_format = u"%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(process)d %(threadName)s %(module)s: " \
                            u"%(lineno)d %(funcName)s(): %(message)s\r\n"
        self.loger = None

        self.__configure_level(level.upper())
        self.__configure_format(log_format)
        self.__configure_handler(log_dir)

    def __configure_level(self, level):
        if level and (level not in ['CRITICAL', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'INFO', 'DEBUG']):
            raise Exception(u"{lvl} is not a valid log level".format(lvl=level))
        self.__level = level or 'INFO'

    def __configure_format(self, log_format):
        if log_format:
            self.__log_format = log_format
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter(self.__log_format)

    def __configure_handler(self, log_dir):
        _dir = '{b_dr}/{l_dr}'.format(b_dr=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), l_dr=log_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(_dir):
            os.mkdir(_dir)
        _filename = "{dr}/{lnf}.log".format(dr=_dir, lnf=self.__log_name)
        self.handler = handlers.WatchedFileHandler(_filename, mode="a", encoding="utf-8")
        self.handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)

    def create_logger(self):
        _loger = logging.getLogger(self.__log_name)
        _loger.setLevel(getattr(logging, self.__level))
        _loger.addHandler(self.handler)
        self.loger = _loger
        return _loger
```

Comment: I use logging to see the data recieved for development purposes. It was easier to debug errors/bugs when you see the raw data. But I do not think logging is the only reason of this.

Comment: But logging save to ram. did you have any one cleaner function(with period)?

Comment: What do you mean with period? How can I use that?

Comment: _log = Logger("Orion_EasyTrac").create_logger() in  class Logger !  I haven't idea about of your "Logger".Show finger and want full check-up (i am not fortune teller) ? ***BUT*** for starting point (if Logger not external) Try: help(Logger) or print dir(Logger).I hope helpful. Best regards !

Comment: @FallenAngel Did you solve your problem? I have a very similar one. I'm using multithreading's Listening and Client methods to create a socket connection. My program when running alone uses around 600 MB, but if I put it in a loop using socket to change a config file and then running it, it increases the memory at each run until it crashes after 30 runs or so. I tried to delete the objects created at the end of a loop, but it doesn't work. So I think it's an issue with socket.